# Return text when column name not found in data R

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I'm trying to create a function that takes in a data frame and a column name in the data. If the column name is not found in the data, the function should return "check column name". If the column name is found, it should return "(column name) text here (row name) text here (max value of the column)".

What I've done so far is

```
Function <- function(data,col) {
data<-data[, col]
if(is.na(col)) {
print ("check column name")
} else {
print(paste(colnames(data), "text here", rownames(data), "text here", max(data))
}
}
```

but this won't work.

I think the problem is that is don't know how to define the "if column name is not found in data". I also tried

```
if(col==NA)
if(data==NA)
```

but they don't work either. I also am not sure how to print value, such as the row and column names, in the middle of text which the function should return when the column name is found in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%in%` -

```
Function <- function(data, col) {
  if(!col %in% names(data)) {
    print ("check column name")
  } else {
    max_row <- which.max(data[, col])
    print(paste("Column:", col, "Row:", rownames(data)[max_row],
                "MaxValue:", data[max_row, col]))
  }
}

Function(iris, "test")
[1] "check column name"

Function(iris, "Sepal.Width")
[1] "Column: Sepal.Width Row: 16 MaxValue: 4.4"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the "check column name" works now exactly as I wanted! However, I somehow am still not able to print the text I want to when the column is found. Is colnames() the right command for the column name and rownames() for the row name?

Comment: @Joe are you looking to print the row name and column name where max value appears? Add an example of expected output when column is present in data.

Comment: I am looking to print the max value of the column that is present in the data. So for example for function(iris, "COL"), the output should be "In COL the biggest value is in (row name here) which is (max value here)".

Comment: @Joe See updated answer. If it answers your question, consider marking it correct using tick mark at the top left of this answer.